# How use hostvars from multiple hosts in one variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, aerospike

I want to add more servers to Aerospike cluster. For that i want to use facts from gather_facts. Here the example how i do it for one server.
How i can add all hosts which works with my playbook ? I don't want to use hosts from groups in inventory - because i'm using dynamical inventory.

```
heartbeat {
    mode mesh
    port 3002
    mesh-seed-address-port {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} 3002
    interval 150
    timeout 10
}

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  I would suggest writing a dynamic inventory script (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html)

That said if you're insistent about using facts to dynamically generate inventory you can use the [add host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) module in a with_items (or other loop type) loop.